# Why use SQS/AMQ in python when you can just use asyncio.create_task?

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery, python-asyncio, amazon-sqs

Given the downside that you're now unable to independently scale your API service and workers, you still do have the upside of lesser network latencies since nothing needs to be enqueued into the task queue, and nothing needs to be polled from a remote task queue.

Are there any notable reasons to still use SQS in the context of python?

Comment: Reliability? `asyncio.create_task` lives as long as current process and can die unexpectedly, while SQS gives much higher level of protection against random failures.

Comment: @STerliakov , agreed. The "API service" which triggers the `create_task` is meant to live until killed (since its a server), and is also setup in HA mode, with multiple replicas. Wouldn't this now be protected against failures? even with the SQS case, once a worker has pulled a task, and died amidst processing it, that particular task is gone for good isnt it?

Comment: Not really: your worker pulls the task. Then this task enters a "visibility timeout" period, during which it is invisible to other workers. When worker completes the task, it can delete message. If a worker dies, it simply doesn't delete the message, and so message becomes available again after timeout expiration. (and do replicas of your worker share the same process somehow? If not, how should tasks created with `asyncio.create_task` be "passed" to another replica in case of failure?)